# How to turn times into categories using R

Tags: r, time, lubridate

I am looking to create a function to turn times of the day into categories. Ideally I would like to create 3 categories of "morning", "afternoon" and "night". I would like to create the function so that it works with the lubridate::now(). Thus far I've tried these various code but none have worked. Help would be greatly appreciated:

```
daytime <- function(x) if (x>hm(05:00) || x<hm(12:00)){message("goodmorning")}
ifelse (x>hm(12:00) || x<hm(18:00)) {message("good afternoon")}
ifelse (x>hm(18:00)) {message("good evening")}
```

---

```
daytime2 <- function(x) {dates <- as.POSIXlt(as.numeric(x) / 1000, origin = "1970-01-01")
mutate(hour = cut(as.numeric(format(date, "%H")),
                breaks = c(05, 12, 18, 24),
                labels = c("good morning", "good afternoon", "good evening")))}
```

plz help.

Comment: try installing ghostscript? - https://www.ghostscript.com/

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work on mac.

Comment: I've no experience on macs. You could try the mac installers here: http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/ .  You could also try installing the texlive package or the MacTEX-2016 package - ghostscript should be part of it. Otherwise you may need to build ghostcript from source.